# Is "fanning over" merely a corruption of "fawning over"?

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage

I just heard someone today say that some person was "fanning over" some celebrity. I've always heard it as "fawning over."

I see plenty of examples around the web of people using "fanning over," but am not having much luck finding anything about its usage or etymology.

By the way, when I say "corruption", I'm not making a value judgment, but referring to the technical term "linguistic corruption."

Does anyone know of the origin of this phrase?

Comment: Sounds like an 'eggcorn' (which is a nicer way of saying 'mistake').

Comment: har har, I've never heard _eggcorn_. That's almost as endearing as Piglet's _haycorn_.

Comment: It could be an eggcorn, or it may be derived from _fan_ (as in being a fan of someone). Hard to tell without being able to ask the person in question.

Comment: You don't have to ask the person in question. Just google it to see hundreds of examples: https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=%22fanning%20over%22

Comment: There is a difference: "fanning" would be to show your appreciation, whereas "fawning" is being obsequious, AKA crawling.

Comment: @labyrinth [eggcorn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eggcorn). 'fanning over' historical meant 'spreading out over (like a fan)'. Eggcorns aren't necessarily wrong, but they can be. 'Fanning over' may really be meant as 'acting like a fan around', whose synonym could be the modern ['stanning'](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/stanning). Whether 'fanning' over is a corruption/eggcorn, I don't think it is clear; 'to fawn' over does sound a little old-fashioned to me. As the kids these days say, it's all good.

Comment: btw, when I said "corruption", I meant "linguistic corruption" which is a technical term, not a judgment of whether the new usage is good. I think I'll add this if I can still edit my questions. Indeed, "fawning" doesn't even come from "fawn", but from an Old English verb meaning to rejoice (and came to mean sycophantic praise of someone or something).

Comment: Interesting. I've no idea to the true etymology for "fanning over" something but the mental image I get is someone literally fanning themselves (with a fan, or at least making the motion) because they've become hot (temperature) over whatever is worth "fanning over"

Comment: "Fanboying" or even "fanboying over" is pretty popular slang nowadays. My guess is that "fanning over" is either an intentional (or unintentional) take on that.